# How to identify is a blog post has been selected or not?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working with a Tumblr blog template in which I need to differentiate between blog articles/posts in their collapsed and expanded state. Specifically, I am trying to apply a CSS property (for border) which must only apply to the blog posts when they are being shown in the grid in the collapsed state and must not apply when the visitor selects the blog to read it further.

This is the change I have made to the template:

```
    div.posts-holder article:hover
    {
        border: 1px #BDBDBD solid;
        box-shadow: 7px 7px 3px #D8D8D8;
    }
```

Also, this is how the div.posts-holder looks like (not the complete code, only a snippet to give an idea)

```
<section class="the-posts">

    <div class="posts-holder
    {block:IndexPage} posts-grid{/block:IndexPage}">


        {block:IndexPage}<div class="grid-sizer"></div>{/block:IndexPage}


        {block:Posts}

        <article id="{PostID}" class="type_{PostType} {TagsAsClasses}" rel="{ReblogURL}">

            <div class="article-content">
```

Here's a link to a dummy blog I created to illustrate the problem: 
[Example Blog Link](http://blogsamplefortheme.tumblr.com/)
Observe that on hover, each blog post gets a shadowed border. I don't need this once I am actually reading one of these posts.

How can I do this using JavaScript or any other technique? Is there a way I can look for the state of the post?

Comment: Can you link to an example page with your theme applied? We need to know what changes about the `<article>` elements when they're expanded to tell you how to detect that with JS/CSS. For example, a class could be added on click or the styles applied to the `article` could be changed.

Comment: How about .height() of the box?

Comment: @freshtop: I have added the example link, please check. TimSPQR: could you elaborate how I may use .height()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your example page, the `posts-holder` div also has a `posts-grid` class on the grid page, but it doesn't on the pages that only show one article. So you just have to change your CSS hover rule from

```
div.posts-holder article:hover
```

to

```
div.posts-holder.posts-grid article:hover
```

That way it will only be applied to the articles when they're in a grid.

Comment: OMG! that worked wonders! So simple, I feel kinda stupid for missing that, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

here is a answer of the main heading of the question:

> How to identify is a blog post has been selected or not?

this can be achieve by making an object... just look at this code:

**HTML**

```
   <div id="article1" onclick="selected("article1")"> </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
   var click= {};
    var selected = function(a){


          click[a] = "selected";
}
```

so when ever you want to know that if this div is selected then just check that in `click` object, is a property named `article1` is present or not if true then do stuff else then dont